# Is there a proof of quadratic reciprocity using $p$-adic numbers?

Tags: number-theory, alternative-proof, p-adic-number-theory, quadratic-reciprocity

I know that the quadratic reciprocity can be regarded as a special case of Artin reciprocity (class field theory), and we can get it by considering the cyclotomic extension of $\mathbb{Q}_{p}$. However, I want to know if there's any proof of quadratic reciprocity that doesn't use any stronger result, but only uses some properties of $p$-adic numbers. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are fine proofs through cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, without any reference to $p$-adic numbers at all. Do you want to avoid (cyclotomic) field extensions, and how do you feel about proofs without $p$-adic numbers?

Comment: @Servaes I know some proofs that doesn't use $p$-adic numbers at all. One of the reason that $p$-adic numbers are useful is that we know much about its algebraic and analytic properties. I think there might be a way to use such tools.

Comment: Might be worth asking on MSO with a link back to here : https://mathoverflow.net/

Comment: Now posted also on MathOverflow: [Is there a proof of quadratic reciprocity using $p$-adic numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/327103)